# Code works on Gingerbread (2.3.6) not on ICS (4.0.4)

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

- I have an application which was developed and tested on Android 2.3.6 and before
  and below. It works fine.
- I Run the app on my new Micromax A110 with Android 4.0.4 and it crashes when i launch activity B from Activity A and press the back button (or Activity C/D/E from A ) with the following error log **vv**

> 01-10 18:35:44.372: E/AndroidRuntime(18378): FATAL EXCEPTION: Timer-1
>   01-10 18:35:44.372: E/AndroidRuntime(18378):
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Must be called from main thread of
>   process 01-10 18:35:44.372: E/AndroidRuntime(18378):  at
>   android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1373)
>   01-10 18:35:44.372: E/AndroidRuntime(18378):  at
>   android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:437)
>   01-10 18:35:44.372: E/AndroidRuntime(18378):  at
>   android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackImmediate(FragmentManager.java:454)
>   01-10 18:35:44.372: E/AndroidRuntime(18378):  at
>   android.app.Activity.onBackPressed(Activity.java:2134) 01-10
>   18:35:44.372: E/AndroidRuntime(18378):    at
>   com.vwap.friends.MygoBack(MyDialog.java:90) 01-10 18:35:44.372:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(18378):  at
>   com.vwap.friends.MyDialog$3.run(MyDialog.java:83) 01-10
>   18:35:44.372: E/AndroidRuntime(18378):    at
>   java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:284)

- I am completely unaware of the concept of fragments yet (i plan to work on that asap) and it looks like the error has something to do with it.

I don't know where to begin from. Do i start by reading about Fragments or can i quickly fix this and release my application?

Comment: cant seem to format the logcat output, help?

Comment: add some code where you are facing the problem

Comment: is `ChandlerDialog` one of your classes? Can you please post the source of it and mark line 83?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> try to Use **runOnUiThread(Runnable**
> **action).**

**Or**

you can Also Try with **Handler**:

```
final Runnable YOURVIEW = new Runnable()
{
    public void run() 
    {
        SampleMethod(); // Put your Method What you want change
        handler.postDelayed(this, timeout);
    }
};

handler.postDelayed(changeView, timeout);
```

Answer (score 2):

You're performing a network operation on the main thread. If your target SDK is 11 or higher this will throw a `NetworkOnMainThreadException` , because this behaviour can block the UI and lead to an unresponsive app.

You could use an [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to get around this, loading the data in its `doInBackground(..)`.

Answer (score 0):

Even I am facing a similar problem, but i think you have to include `android_support_v4.jar` file for compatibility over all versions of Android.